# SQL multiple dates query

Tags: sql

I'm working on a query where I have to find 3 or more orders on a part that will have multiple date ranges. The problem I'm having is that it looks like the query isn't looking at the date ranges specifically...it's looking at a complete range of dates.

```
 SELECT partnumber, count(orders.partorderid) as numberoforders 
 FROM orders
 WHERE(orderdate between '2013-10-07' and '2013-10-13') or (orderdate between '2013-10-14' and '2013-10-20')
 GROUP BY partnumber
 HAVING COUNT(partorderid) > 2
```

The query returns the numberoforders between 10/07-10/20, not 10/07-10/13 and 10/14-10/20???

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT partnumber,
    SUM(CASE WHEN orderdate BETWEEN '2013-10-07' and '2013-10-13' THEN 1 END) week1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN orderdate BETWEEN '2013-10-14' and '2013-10-20' THEN 1 END) week2
FROM orders
GROUP BY partnumber
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN orderdate BETWEEN '2013-10-07' and '2013-10-13' THEN 1 END) > 2
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN orderdate BETWEEN '2013-10-14' and '2013-10-20' THEN 1 END) > 2
```

Or you might prefer:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT partnumber,
        SUM(CASE WHEN orderdate BETWEEN '2013-10-07' and '2013-10-13' THEN 1 END) week1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN orderdate BETWEEN '2013-10-14' and '2013-10-20' THEN 1 END) week2
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY partnumber
) t WHERE week1 > 2 AND week2 > 2
```

which has a less repetition.

FYI, if `orderdate` is a date, you are fine. But if it has and date a and a non-zero time, you will be missing orders that are after 2013-10-13 00:00:00 and before 2013-10-14 00:00:00.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The only problem I'm having with this is that it shows blanks or < 3 in week1 or week2 if one of the conditions are met. Can these values be eliminated from the results?

Comment: It depends what you mean by eliminated. Do you want to have the value in the offending column as NULL, or remove the whole record for the part number?

Comment: Remove the record for the part number from the query results.

Comment: Easy...simply change `WHERE week1 > 2 OR week2 > 2` TO `WHERE week1 > 2 AND week2 > 2`

Comment: I was never able to get the second example to run due to an incorrect syntax error near WHERE. I changed the OR to AND in the HAVING clause from the first example and the output is great, but now it's missing values. Some of the orders that were > 3 aren't pulling.

Comment: Were these parts with two or fewer orders during the *other* week?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...been away. Anyway's, yes these parts had two or fewer during the other week. I'm still needing to display any part that had 3 or more orders in the given date ranges. Ideally, the query would display the part, partorderid (there would be 3 or more), and orderdate (3 or more). A part could show up in only one week, or every week, but needs to be grouped in its corresponding date range. I hope this makes some type of sense.